# Unity Hololens System.web.httputils doesn't exist in target Framework

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, system.web, azure-spatial-anchors

I am trying to build an app for the Hololens. It already worked a lot of times, as I am developing since about 10 months. But all of a sudden, a reference is broken. I have appended a screenshot.

[image: Error Message]

I have already tried (for weeks):

1. Downgrading to version before, I also tried all unity versions available since 2018
2. Reimporting all assets
3. Running a virus scanner because crypto mining malware can affect imports
4. Talked to Microsoft support
5. Did manual imports with a csc.rsp file
6. Tried building in unity and running in vs code.
7. Tried to delete the dlls
8. Tried to add missing dlls in a lot of places.
9. Creating a whole new project but error persists.
10. A lot of other things I can not remember right now.

It looks like Unity is not able to copy System.web.dll into the Temp\Staging folder. Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Since the build completes in the end, did you test deploying the app?

We have a similar list of errors when building our app, but it still works as expected when deployed to a HoloLens.
It appears similar bugs have appeared a number of times before as well:

https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/3939
https://fogbugz.unity3d.com/default.asp?1146307_k5pfi2qqltmcvqm5

Comment: I have built it in Unity with a result of 'succeeded'. But if I want to deploy it via Visual Studio, `Error LNK1181 cannot open input file 'C:\LeARn\Max\HoloLens\Projects\MultiUserPunTest\App\build\bin\ARM64\Release\GameAssembly.lib'` error is thrown. So after all it seems like Unity didn't build it right.

Comment: Ok, maybe something else has changed in your configuration? Some developers have run into issues when building with the latest SDK after upgrading to Windows version 2004, downgrading the build to 17763 (hololens 1) or 18362 (hololens 2) might serve as a workaround. You should probably report this as an issue with Unity though. 
Also, if you haven’t already, check out the Holodevelopers’ slack channel at https://holodevelopersslack.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Another thing, even if it did work before, your build path looks a bit long, you should consider moving it closer to the root:  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-base-02#creating-the-unity-project